# How to use LOAD_REGISTER with Typoscript select?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-8.x

In Typoscript, I want to use register together with select. 
I have a row with values: firstname, lastname, mail. I want to assign it to register somehow, and then use it for another plugin:

```
page {
 10 = CONTENT
 10 {
  table = tx_my_custom_table
  select {
    pidInList = 21
    where = uid=1234
    selectFields = firstname,lastname,mail
  }
  renderObj = COA
  renderObj {
    10 = LOAD_REGISTER
    10 {
       /*how to assign values to register???*/
    }
  }
 }
}

plugin.tx_powermail.settings.setup.prefill {
    email = TEXT
    email.value = {register.mail}
}
```

I tried a lot of combinationes with data and field, but it didn't work.

Adding the SELECT statement to the plugin section is possible, but in reality I have 30 fields, and I don't want 30 database queries for one row.

Answer (score 0):

in general you assign a value to a register name:

```
10 = LOAD_REGISTER
10 {
    register1 = value1

    register2 = 10
}
```

but you have `stdWrap`functionality and so you can use also:

```
10 = LOAD_REGISTER
10 {
    register3.field = field1

    register4.data = date:U
    register4.strftime = %Y-%m-%d
}
```

**Edit:**

---

you may use `cObject` if no `stdWrap`-functionality is given (in older TYPO3 versions):

```
10 = LOAD_REGISTER
10 {
    register5.cObject = TEXT
    register5.cObject.field = field1

    register6.cObject = TEXT
    register6.cObject.data = date:U
    register6.cObject.strftime = %Y-%m-%d
}
```

---

Accessing registers can be done like:

```
20 = TEXT
20.data = register:register1

30 = TEXT
30.value = {register:register2}
30.stdWrap.insertData = 1
```

remember:
only the last value is accessible - unless you use `RESTORE_REGISTER` to pop the register stack

Comment: This works with usual values, but I need something that works with a SELECT result. I tried already anything with field and data, but without result. 
I think the access inside renderObj needs something more, as it is an array and not a single value. But I don't know what it is?

Comment: You always need a context. Your plugin.tx_powermail.... can not know your registers if it is called outside of the page rendering, or before the select is rendered.

Comment: Depending on your TYPO3 version there is no direct stdWrap functionality build in. you might use the detour with a `cObject` (answer edited)